# Maven compile fails, Maven install succeeds

Tags: maven, compilation

I am at a loss to explain why I have a **Maven compile** fails and a **Maven install** succeeds on the same project. Context: running Eclipse and m2e, everything compiles in the workspace. Run configurations > Maven compile fails (symbol not found) but Maven install succeeds. So, my understanding is that *Maven install invokes a Maven compile*. The Maven compile fail: **symbol not found** is on a .java test class's ancestor class. Interestingly, doing a run as > JUnit test on the class shows a compile failure ClassNotFound on the same ancestor class. Can you help?
 - Chuck

Comment: what happens from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse all java files are compiled from source folders to `target/classes` (it can be changed). Eclipse uses to compile all classes - from pom with all scopes (compile, test, provided etc.) and other projects (check if your project depends on other open in workspace).
When you run `maven install` - maven checks if all classes have been compiled and create jar package. It does not know how the classes have been compiled? By maven or by eclipse?

If you compile by maven compile (install package) - maven uses only libraries with scope compile/provided. It does not use any other dependencies.

You can make a test. Add to your pom:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.8</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Now use in one of your class from src/main/java @Test annotation. In eclipse project will compile. But when you run `mvn clean install` the compilation error will be displayed (No such class Test).

Comment: Thanks @ajozwik., Ancestor class is in /src/test/java in proj-dao. Descendent is in proj-test. Proj-test pom.xml lists proj-dao pom.xml as dependecy. Doesn't Maven compile know how to find/compile a dependent?

Comment: See [Guide to using attached tests](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html).If you want to use test classes from other module you have to add it to as test dependency.In ancestor project add `<build><plugins><plugin>groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId><artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId><executions><execution><goals><goal>test-jar</goal></goals></execution></executions></plugin></plugins></build>`.In descendent add:`<dependency><groupId>proj-dao</groupId><artifactId>foo</artifactId><version>1.0</version><type>test-jar</type><scope>test</scope></dependency>`

Comment: thanks. The ancestor's project has a pom parent and the <goal>test-jar</goal> elements are there. I added the <type> and <scope> elements in the pom of the descendent class. Still, I get "cannot find symbol". Thanks for the help. There must be something else going on.

Comment: Try remove `<scope>test</scope>` or change scope to compile. I've never tried. Why you use test class in normal code?

Comment: Thanks. Really, it's one test project wanting to use components from another test project. I think you are right, i.e. that the needed components are not being jar'ed for discovery by the compiler, and thus <unable to locate symbol>. In fact, having the <build> element in the <parent> pom may not direct <goal>test-jar</goal> in the pom of the proj-dao. Hmmm. - Chuck